# easyui работа с БД

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

Взял исходники на http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud.php, переделал под свою базу. Все отлично работает до момента, когда я пытаюсь подсоединить к таблице, в которой индекс обозначен не как id, а как table.id или table_id, ну или любое другое, отличное от id. В данном случае или изменения в базе не происходят, или меняются все записи.

Например для функции изменения поля:

```
 function editUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit');
                $('#fm').form('load',row);
                url = 'edit.php?id='+row.id;
            }
        }
```

Имеем такую запись в файле edit.php:

```
<?php
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['table.name']);

$conn = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db('Base', $conn);
mysql_query ("SET NAMES `utf8`"); 

$sql = "update Table set table.name='$name' where table.id=$id";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
    echo json_encode(array(
        'table.id' => $id,
        'table.name' => $name,
    ));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('errorMsg'=>'Some errors occured.'));
}
?>
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А какие есть колонки в таблице `Table`?

Comment: В тестовой таблице: contacts_id, contacts_name, contacts_phone, contacts_dept.

Comment: @Руслан Берденников **1.** Функции `mysql_` умерли, их использовать не следует. **2.** Берите имена таблиц и полей в запросах в апострофы (которые на клавише Ё сидят).

Comment: @Visman
1. Почитаю про это.
2. При взятии в апостроф, например, `table.id` у меня происходило изменение всех имеющихся в таблице записей.

Comment: @Руслан Берденников в запросах имена таблиц от столбцов отделяются точкой. Соответственно если хотите обратиться к столбцу id в таблице table пишите table.'id' ...... и как следствие имена столбцов в таблице не должно содержать точку. Т.е. имя столбца не может быть table.id, только table_id... Ошибка не может быть в плагине. Т.к. он не работает с б.д. Это всего лишь стилизованное отображение.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский
К сожалению, прямо сейчас не могу еще раз все перепроверить, т.к. проект на работе. Завтра попробую еще раз с учетом апострофов и устаревших функций. Но, table_id у меня так же не работало.

Comment: @Руслан Берденников возьмите любую программу которая работет с БД, например SQLYog или Navicat или в phpmyadmin выполните свой sql запрос напрямую там ручками. Уверен что вернет вам ошибку =) На основе неё можно будет что-то дальше понять

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский
Об этом не подумал, спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский
update `Contacts ` set `contacts_name`='123',`contacts_phone`='234',`contacts_dept`='345' where `id1`='10'; в том же phpmyadmin прекрасно выполняется.

Comment: При этом если в самом запросе жестко указать id - то обновление происходит ($sql = "update `Contacts` set `contacts_name`='$contacts_name',`contacts_phone`='$contacts_phone',`contacts_dept`='$contacts_dept' where `id1`='10'";)
т.е. проблема именно в передачи переменной. буду копать дальше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге получилось все настроить. Но для этого потребовалось добавлять в DataGrid поле с ID. После этого начинает все работать.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо поменять `sql`

Вместо
`$sql = "update Table set table.name='$name' where table.id=$id";`

Написать:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Contacts
SET `contacts_name`='$contacts_name', `contacts_phone`='$contacts_phone', `contacts_dept`='$‌​contacts_dept'
WHERE `contacts_id`=$id";
```

Comment: Ну, я имена таблиц первоначально писал для примера. По факту запрос такой:
`$sql = "update Contacts set contacts_name='$contacts_name',contacts_phone='$contacts_phone',contacts_dept='$contacts_dept' where contacts_id=$id";`

Comment: Я подправил sql в своем ответе, но так в принципе в Вашем запросе все выглядит правильно. Видимо ошибка где-то еще...

Comment: Самое интересное, что как только меняешь имя в запросе и имя колонки в базе на "id", все сразу же работает корректно. Может быть ограничение самого easyui, хотя вряд ли.

Comment: не понимаю тогда, в чем проблема? в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: проблема в том, что если изменить "id" на "something.id"/"something_id"/"somethingid" - ничего не работает.